# Full width chart cuts off left and right values in ios-charts

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

Using [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and I'm trying to figure out how to display a full width line chart using ios-chart. Currently my chart looks like the following below:

[image: ios-charts]

My Code looks like the following:

```
let chartView = LineChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height))

chartView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

chartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false
chartView.dragEnabled = false
chartView.setScaleEnabled(false)
chartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
chartView.setViewPortOffsets(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0)

chartView.legend.enabled = false
chartView.leftAxis.enabled = false
chartView.leftAxis.spaceTop = 0.4
chartView.leftAxis.spaceBottom = 0.4
chartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
chartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
chartView.clipValuesToContentEnabled = true

let xAxis = chartView.xAxis
xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: MegaTheme.fontName, size: 12.0)!
xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.black
xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
xAxis.granularity = 1.0
xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = true
xAxis.enabled = true
xAxis.labelPosition = .bottomInside
xAxis.labelCount = goal.progress.count + 1

chartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5)
generateGoalLineChartData(chartView, goal: goal)

return chartView
```

Even when avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled enabled I still get first and last value clipped.

Answer (score 5):

For above Chart margin issue you need to comment below line or change value as per your requirements:

```
chartView.setViewPortOffsets(left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0)
```

comment above line so Chart will use its default margin  or use as per your requirement like below :

```
chartView.setViewPortOffsets(left: 20, top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20)
```

Hope this will help you to set your viewPort.